# How to force auto upgrade control dependency in a debian package

Tags: unix, debian

I am installing a custom debian package on debian 6 machine.

This is my control file

```
Package: [[name]]
Version: 5.1
Section: hello/world
Priority: Optional
Architecture: all
Essential: no
Depends: my-dependent-package (>> 0.2.1)
Installed-Size: 1000
Maintainer: Test test@test.com
Description: _DESCRIPTION_
```

Here the my-dependent-package doesnt get auto upgraded when newer versions are released.

i always do sudo apt-get update before installing.

installing the debian from an internal mirror and using
sudo apt-get install mypackage
the dependent package "my-dependent-package" is also available in the same internal mirror.

the internal mirrors are defined in /etc/apt/sources.list

both the packages come from same mirror

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 my-package : Depends: my-dependent-package (>> 0.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Installation succeeds when I manually install the "my-dependent-package". I was expecting it to be auto installed by the "my-package" as I have mentioned it in control file.

How can I enable it ?

Comment: How are you installing your packages? Via `apt-get/aptitude` from your customer repository or directly via `dpkg -i file.deb`?

Comment: updated the question. 

installing the debian from an internal mirror and using sudo apt-get install mypackage the dependent package "my-dependent-package" is also available in the same internal mirror.

the internal mirrors are defined in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: And what is the output of `apt-get install mypackage`? What error does it show? Also try `apt-cache showpkg mypackage` and `apt-cache showpkg my-dep-pkg`

Comment: when do you expect the upgrade of `my-dependent-package` to happen? just by installing the `[[name]]` package? where should the upgraded version of `my-dependent-package` come from (which repo)?

Comment: Updated the question with the error, both the packages are available in same mirror and individual installation works.

Answer (score 0):

Debian assigns priorities to suites and packages.

Most likely your local repository has a low priority, which results in being excluded from automatic updates.

Configure `apt` to assign a higher priority to your repository, so it get's automatically selected.

See the [AptPreferences documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) for more information.

(It's really impossible to give you a walkthrough without more knowledge on your actual setup)